# DROP DOWN LIST ID

Tags: .net

can two drop down lists in two different web content forms be assigned the same ID?

Comment: Hi, you mean the id attribute of the dropdown list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  You can even have two controls with the same ID on the *same* page, which happens for any of the repeater controls.  The only rule that matters is that two controls cannot have the same ID inside of the same [NamingContainer](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2007/02/25/Understanding-the-naming-container-hierarchy-of-ASP.NET-databound-controls.aspx).

Note, in Asp.Net 4.0, it is possible to directly set the client side id of a control.  In that case, disregard what I have said above.